# Change decimal separator in GDB

Tags: ubuntu, gdb, decimal-point

Is there a way to change decimal separator in gdb, without changing it in the whole system?

I have a French ubuntu 14.04 (with comma as decimal separator). But in gdb, any floating point written with a dot (for example `p 2.0`) leads to "invalid number" message; and comma is interpreted as list separator...

I have tried to create a gdbinit file with `set environment LC_NUMERIC="C"` within, but it didn't work...

Comment: In fact a comment in a gdb's source file tells the opposite: `a '.' always indicates a decimal floating point number regardless of the radix.`. And then the code:      `else if (!got_dot && *p == '.')        got_dot = 1;`. So it seems that `gdb` must accept '.' as a separator.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In fact, the problem here is not a problem of radix, but a problem of system locale.
If I type the command `export LC_NUMERIC="C"` in a shell, and then run gdb, it works. Now I wanted to include this command in gdbinit, but it is not taken in account by gdb...

Comment: Try run your `gdb` in the command line in this way: `LC_NUMERIC=C gdb`. This way you don't have to export the environment var.

Comment: Seems that this problem will be resolved in gdb 7.8: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb/+bug/1341125

Comment: Greg, did you build `gdb` yourself from gdb's source or you use `gdb` from your ubuntu?

Comment: It is Ubuntu's gdb (probably installed by apt-get)

Comment: I think that is why I didn't manage to reproduce your error. I downloaded gdb7.7's source from their site http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb, built it and could not see the error message. As a workaround you can try to build gdb from the source http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/download/ and see if you get the error with this gdb.

Comment: Your OS uses comma as decimal separator too?

Comment: I did an experiment. First I set`export LC_ALL=en_US` and run gdb, then I set `export LC_ALL=es_ES` and also run gdb

Comment: By the way: `$ LC_ALL=es_ES printf "%f\n" 3,1415` prints `3,141500`