# Can GDB correctly parse C-style hexadecimal floating-point numbers?

Tags: c, floating-point, gdb

I cannot manage to make GDB print correctly some C-style hexadecimal floating-point numbers, see:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb) p 0xa.0p-4
$1 = 6
```

Here `$1` should be `0.625` but my GDB seems to see `0xa.0p` as decimal `10` and does a subsequent addition with `-4`.
What is wrong with what I ask GDB to print?
I could not find any relevant documentation on how GDB handles hexadecimal floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is wrong with what I ask GDB to print?

Apparently it's a bug with gdb.

Hexadecimal floating point constants with a negative exponent give a wrong result with gdb.

I tried with the latest source release gdb 7.9 (Feb 20, 2015) on Linux and hexadecimal floating point constants with a positive exponent are supported:

```
(gdb) p/f 0x00.1p0
$1 = 0.0625
(gdb) p/f 0x00.1p1
$2 = 0.125
```

but if the exponent is negative, then the result is wrong:

```
(gdb) p/f 0x00.1p-1
$3 = -0.9375
```

The right and expected result is `0.031250`.

Comment: @hdl I cannot find any open bug on gdb Bugzilla https://www.sourceware.org/bugzilla would you like to open one? Otherwise I can file it myself.

Comment: For the `Invalid number` error, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865689/change-decimal-separator-in-gdb#comment38649027_24865689

Comment: @hdl good point, I remove this point of my answer to avoid unnecessary noise

Comment: Neither could I. If you already have a Sourceware Bugzilla account, please file it and report here. Otherwise I can do it. ;)

Comment: Thanks, I also reported it to Ubuntu https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb/+bug/1448146 as per https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Bug-Reporting.html#Bug-Reporting

Comment: FWIW the fix to this landed today.  It will appear in gdb 10.